# Trait with generic container return type

Tags: rust

I have this trait:

```
pub trait S<T>{
    fn s(&self) -> Box<dyn S<T>>;
}
```

but what if I want it to be thread safe sometimes and sometimes not?

I want to be generic on the container that has the return type:

```
pub trait S<T, Container>{
    fn s(&self) -> Container<dyn S<T>>;
}
```

is there a way to do it?
but I get

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0109]: type arguments are not allowed for this type
 --> src/lib.rs:2:30
  |
2 |     fn s(&self) -> Container<dyn S<T>>;
  |                              ^^^^^^^^ type argument not allowed

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0109`.
```

Comment: Perhaps you would like to read about [family traits](http://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2016/11/03/associated-type-constructors-part-2-family-traits/).

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem that is easily solved using GATs, if you have access to them.

The [GAT blog post](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2021/08/03/GATs-stabilization-push.html) actually covers your exact use case:

```rust
trait PointerFamily {
    type Pointer<T>: Deref<Target = T>;

    fn new<T>(value: T) -> Self::Pointer<T>;
}

struct ArcFamily;
struct RcFamily;

impl PointerFamily for ArcFamily {
    type Pointer<T> = Arc<T>;
    ...
}
impl PointerFamily for RcFamily {
    type Pointer<T> = Rc<T>;
    ...
}

struct MyStruct<P: PointerFamily> {
    pointer: P::Pointer<String>,
}
```

In your case ([playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=21337865e8f415f17af82c83b2fe72f9)):

```rust
#![feature(generic_associated_types)]
use std::ops::Deref;
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::rc::Rc;

pub trait PointerFamily {
    type Pointer<T: ?Sized>: Deref<Target = T>; //Note the ?sized to allow for dyn 

    fn new<T>(value: T) -> Self::Pointer<T>;
}

struct ArcFamily;
struct RcFamily;

impl PointerFamily for ArcFamily {
    type Pointer<T: ?Sized> = Arc<T>;
    
    fn new<T>(value: T) -> Self::Pointer<T> {
        Arc::new(value)
    }
}
impl PointerFamily for RcFamily {
    type Pointer<T: ?Sized> = Rc<T>;
    
    fn new<T>(value: T) -> Self::Pointer<T> {
        Rc::new(value)
    }
}

pub trait S<T, Container: PointerFamily>{
    fn s(&self) -> Container::Pointer<dyn S<T, Container>>;
}
```